# Can we set the record straight on this optics question?

Tags: discussion

This popular question [Why can't the human eye focus to make blurry photos/video clear?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/600686/why-cant-the-human-eye-focus-to-make-blurry-photos-video-clear)
 has unfortunately been overrun by incorrect answers and comments.  I'm seeking to draw attention to this in the hope that it can still be straightened out.  At the root of the problems is a confusion on the relationship between imaging and convolution.

What is being asserted in a top comment and a top answer is that a blurry image cannot be deblurred because the image "is a convolution".  While it is true that a blurry image is a convolution with some point spread function, this is emphatically *not* why your eye cannot deblur them.  **All light propagation is described by convolution with some point spread function**, and your eye automatically focuses to deal with this; the reason why your eye cannot defocus a blurry image is **because the phase information is not recorded in an image**.  If images recorded both the phase and amplitude of a light field, then you could deblur an out-of-focus image by simply letting light from the image freely propagate to the focal plane (because of hyperbolicity of the equations of motion, if you like).

The top answer to the linked question is highly misleading for the above reason.  The second and third answers are correct, but they're getting sidelined right now.  (Disclosure: The third answer is mine.)  Is there any way we can fix this?

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing to "fix" here. While it may bother you that an answer you see as misleading is a top-voted answer, votes are - for better or worse - not a measure of correctness, but of how many people that have read an answer found it convincing/helpful/useful/correct/had some other positive feeling about it.

They are therefore also at least partly a function simply of *how old* an answer is. If a better answer arrives later, then it will take a while until it surpasses some older answer that may not be as comprehensive or correct, simply because enough people need to see it for it to get as many votes as the older one.

You should vote up answers that you think are useful, and vote down answers that are not. If you think a particular answer deserves more exposure than it has gotten, you can also consider offering a bounty on the question - one of the standard reasons for awarding a bounty is "reward existing answer". Beyond this there is no way to influence how prominent any answer on any post will be, and this is by design.